# Maping Error : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Im using React.js. Im getting error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" in this place

```
enter code here
               } = props;

                 const getInitialState = (initialValues) => {
                 return options.map(option => ({
                 [option[1]]: initialValues.includes(option[1])
                  })).reduce((a, b) => ({...a, ...b}));
                }



enter code here
                 />
                   <Route
                    exact
                   path={"/apply"}
                  render={(props) => <Apply {...props} />}
                />
```

Anybody knows the solution?

Comment: organize your code ,and verify that 'options' it is not empty or null

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `options` is undefined the first render. Anyway, you always to have check "options" is different to undefined:

```
const getInitialState = (initialValues) => {
             if(!options){
              return {};// defined a initial values
             }
             return options.map(option => ({
             [option[1]]: initialValues.includes(option[1])
              })).reduce((a, b) => ({...a, ...b}));
            }
```